# Python: How to assert a two dimensional list exists?

Tags: python

How to:

```
if myList[k][m]:
            # step through each item of the subset
            while i < len(myList[k][m]):
            ...
```

Above is not working. I want to check if the 2nd dimension of that list exists (the 'm').

Comment: How did you get into this mess?  why is it possible for myList to be anything besides a list of lists?

Comment: My algorithm uses "myList [k]" first and then calls itself with "myList ((k,m))" and a sublist is created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try block:

```
try:
    for sublist in mylist:
        for item in sublist:
            pass # do stuff
except TypeError:
    pass # handle stuff here
```

Alternatively:

```
if hasattr(object, '__contains__'):
    pass # the object is iterable!
```

You will have to apply that to every object you want to test the iterable-ness of.

To check the 'k' dimension:

```
if hasattr(myList, '__contains__'): # this is sufficient
    pass # myList is iterable
else:
    raise TypeError
```

If you just want to check the second dimension (the 'm'):

```
if all([hasattr(sublist, '__contains__') for sublist in myList]):
    pass # myList[_] is iterable 
else:
    raise TypeError # handle stuff here
```

Comment: "if hasattr(myList[k][m], '__contains__'):" returns always True even if there is no 'm'.

Comment: @AchmedDurangi you have to apply the function to every sublist in the list as well. Updated answer with examples.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for line in your_list:
    for element in line:
        assert element > whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if myList[k] and isinstance(myList[k], list) and myList[k][m]:
     pass #do stuff

if len(myList) > k and isinstance(myList[k], list) and len(myList[k]) > m:
     pass #do stuff
```

Will any of those work ?

Edit: Added check to see if myList[k] is a list

Comment: 1st solution & 2nd solution: still getting "while m < len(myList[k][m]):
IndexError: string index out of range" meaning the guard still is not effective. (since the list is 1-dimensional in my test case). I think I may have misconstructed the list at assignment. Let me check.

Comment: Okey, try add isinstance(myList[k], list) to the if statement.

Answer (score -1):

Lists in python are slightly different than a two dimensional array in other programming languages. to check if the list has a first dimension you can try typing

```
if len(myList) > 0:
    # Your Code here
```

Now in a list in which each element in another list or a two dimensional list - Each row in the list can have a variable number of columns which is not the same as saying

```
Integer[][] array = new Integer[10][10]
```

in Java or another similar language. Hence you must check the dimensions of each of the elements in the list.

```
if len(myList) > 0:
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if len(myList[i]) > 0:
            for j in range(len(myList[i])):
                # Do something with myList[i][j]
```

Comment: This will raise an Exception if either `myList` or one of the elements of `myList` is not an iterable.